# Could I build a stairway to Heaven?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-constructs

There’s a song called "Stairway to Heaven". I thought I could write a story with it as inspiration. Could I build a stairway to Heaven? It must be possible to walk up the stairway. It should be standard size. How feasible is making a stairway all the way into orbit?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119048/discussion-on-question-by-11bravo-could-i-build-a-stairway-to-heaven).

Comment: I think we should clarify how high you want the stairs. "Into orbit" probably isn't going to happen without something else to give you speed. Are we talking just passed the Kármán line ("into space") or what?

Answer (score 46):

### A stairway into orbit? Probably not, but a stairway to Heaven, YES!

No matter how high you make a stairway, you will die of Hypoxia and/or Hypothermia long before you reach a geosynchronous altitude, thus delivering you straight to Heaven... or another similar fate depending on the variables at play.  For most people this elevation is about 4,500-6,000m (15,000-20,000ft), but a small number of people who are already in good shape and and live at higher altitudes can endure elevations up to about 9,000m (29,000ft). For a short while but will die if they stay at that height for too long.

The Peak of Mount Everest is 8,848m (29,029ft), and many people have died from Hypoxia and/or Hypothermia trying to reach it, and those who do make it typically require oxygen tanks to survive the final climb.  So, if you wanted to make a stairway to Heaven, all you need to do is construct an elevated staircase that goes all the way up to the top of Mt. Everest, and don't let people bring Oxygen tanks with them.  I say elevated specifically because most of the mountain is covered in thick snow; so, if you made it at ground level, it would be perpetually buried in ice.  Now the top of Mt Everest is not certain death for absolutely everyone (See: Habeler and Messner), but it is not survivable indefinitely; so, if you do somehow get to the top, just sit down and relax.  You will be in Heaven soon enough.

### ... but is this actually a stairway to Hell?

Since the OP says it is stairway to "Heaven", and not Valhalla, Reincarnation, or Non-existence, etc. it is important to consider the theological principles that govern that particular model of an afterlife. Most notably: those regarding suicide.

The general concept of Heaven has been shared by many world religions including Christians, Jews, Protestants, Muslims, Zoroastrians, and Greco-Roman Pagans.  The idea of suicide being an unforgivable sin originated with Socrates who claimed that life was a gift from the gods, and that a person who commits suicide offends the gods so badly that they could never enter the Elysian Fields.  From there, this philosophy was was adopted by most of the other faiths that believe in heaven, but all these religions include various caveats where it is not always a damnable offense to kill oneself.

**Christians:** Christianity can generally be divided into 3 major sects, Catholic, Eastern Orthodox, and Protestant.  The official stance of most Protestant churches on sin is that no sin is unforgivable; so, a person who commits suicide without abandoning their faith in Jesus is not damned.  The Eastern Orthodox church teaches that sin is a spiritual sickness, rather than a state of guilt; so, suicide (while considered a sin) is a thing to be pitied, not punished.

Catholics have a more strict stance on suicide, but include the caveat that a no sin can keep you from Heaven unless: You know it is a mortal sin when you do it, you are in a sound state of mind when you do it, and you choose to do it without coercion.  Altitude sickness specifically causes you to lose your mental faculties; so, the final decision to go high enough to die can not be made in a sound state of mind.  Many people make plans to take their life, and then choose against it when the final moment of decision comes.  These people have not committed a mortal sin. Likewise, many people will begin climbing these stairs, and change their mind and turn around.  Also, some people take way to much LSD, and jump out a window and die.  This is also not considered automatic damnation even if it was an intentional act, because the choice to kill oneself was actually made in an altered state of mind. So even from the Catholic perspective, a decision made in a sound state of mind at the bottom of the stairs is only a plan to commit suicide, but the actual choices to take the last few thousand steps to die can not be made in a sound mental condition.  Therefore, you can not commit suicide on these stairs in a way that is a mortal sin.

**Jews:** There have been too many sects of Judaism throughout history to appropriately classify in any coherent way for purposes of this answer, but like Christians, their attitudes on suicide range from it just being a thing to pity, to a severe and malicious sin akin to murder.  However, Judaism says sins can and must be atoned for before entering Heaven, but that sins can be atoned for in death as long as a person's soul is capable of wanting to atone.  So for a Jew, the stairway will probably take you on a path through Gehinom (Hell), but will get most people to Heaven eventually.

**Muslims:** Islam's stance on suicide has been pretty muddied in recent years with the it's frequent association with jihad, but by in large Muslims seem to be similar to Christian Protestants where they believe that suicide is a major sin, but also believe that the only sin that God will not forgive is unbelief.

**Zoroastrians:** The original religion to propose the idea of Heaven & Hell weights one's good and evil at death and submits that person to the afterlife of either God's or Ahriman's design.  While it considers suicide a great act of evil, it can not necessarily undo a lifetime filled with good works.

**Greco-Roman Pagans:** As I mentioned before, Socrates was the first guy to call suicide an unforgivable sin, but most Greco-Roman Pagans did not agree with this stance.  Infact, Socrates's stances on religion were so unpopular in his own religion that he and several of his followers were forced to commit suicide to atone for his heresy, thus proving to the gods and to the people of Greece that he acknowledged his teachings were wrong.

Comment: Hypoxia certainly would get you to Heaven (or Hell) a lot quicker than climbing all the way up :-)  (Depending on one's religious beliefs, of course.  Obviously a practical stairway needs to be pressurized.  I'd suggest a spiral staircase inside a beanstalk tube.

Comment: This answer is a lot darker than seems

Comment: -1 Pretty sure climbing yourself to death counts as suicide i.e. you go to hell.

Comment: @Setsu I've updated my answer to address this concern.

Comment: @Setsu, Not if you don't believe it to be, right? If someone tells you that it's the stairway to heaven, and it's always foggy at the top and no one ever knows of anyone to come back or fall off (i.e. giant meat grinder/vaporizer at the top), then climbing it to reach heaven isn't an act of suicide, but more an act of blind stupidity.

Comment: I’d happily upvote this answer for its dark/spiritual take, if only the units were easily understandable to the greatest number. ;)

Comment: @breversa Metric units added.

Comment: I don't think that your description of Catholic views on sin and disposition of an immortal soul is accurate... it doesn't make a huge difference to the core of the answer, but could do with a citation or explanation or, potentially, removal. It's not really a worldbuilding element in the context of this question anyhow.

Comment: Of course everyone knows that to get to Hell, you need to take the highway, not the stairs.

Comment: @Upper_Case "A mortal sin is defined as a grave action that is committed in full knowledge of its gravity and with the full consent of the sinner’s will." ~ https://www.britannica.com/topic/cardinal-sin. While Catholics list suicide as a possible mortal sin, the official stance of the Catholic Church is that nothing is always a mortal sin unless it is a mortal sin in the context of the sinner's actions.  After all, the only real difference between a damned suicider and a martyr is context.

Comment: The first sentence of the paragraph before the last lacks references :/

Comment: @Nosajimiki Links to the "official stance of the Catholic Church" are what would support the assertions in the answer (more so than an encyclopedia link). While I'll agree that context and intent matter, the official teachings and practices of the Church are a lot more formalized and less lenient than you are presenting here. Your interpretation of state of mind at altitude making mortal sin impossible, for example, is *way* outside of the teachings I'm familiar with, particularly if you intend to die on the stairs to no purpose before you begin the ascent.

Comment: Since the spiritual elements of the answer are totally unrelated to the question in any way (it doesn't ask about anything like that, at all), it reads to me as unnecessary. I'm not interested in debating this in comments (I'm not even Catholic), but I found those references shallow and, worse, inaccurate. Post a question about it on Christianity.SE if you want more detail, but this answer does not suggest that your understanding of Catholicism is deep enough to make such sweeping, precise claims.

Comment: @Upper_Case It is relevant on the level of citing religions that believe in Heaven and the criteria that typically affect if you get there. Since the OP says "stairway to Heaven", and not stairway to Valhalla, or stairway to reincarnation, or stairway to non-existence: it matters.  As for my theological qualifications, I went to Catholic private schools for 5 years. The LSD out a window thing was an actual example used in my sophomore religion class.

Comment: @Nosajimiki It's a stairway to orbit, per the question, with the song *Stairway to Heaven* as its inspiration. Readings of the question may differ. As for theology, comments isn't a good place to discuss it. I was raised Catholic and went through the full suite of religious education for Confirmation. I'm not fussed about the LSD example, but others are more specious (maybe abbreviated for the SE format). Without Reconciliation, any sin can keep one from heaven (not necessarily permanently), with an obvious implication for suicide. "Loophole" is not generally the Catholic theological line.

Comment: I find your description, as I read it, overly precise at best and misleading at worst. Make any changes, or don't, as you feel appropriate, as always.

Answer (score 19):

Quoting [Randall Munroe](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/)

> The reason it's hard to get to orbit isn't that space is high up.
>
> It's hard to get to orbit because you have to go so fast.
>
> Space is about 100 kilometers away. That's far away—I wouldn't want to climb a ladder to get there—but it isn't that far away. If you're in Sacramento, Seattle, Canberra, Kolkata, Hyderabad, Phnom Penh, Cairo, Beijing, central Japan, central Sri Lanka, or Portland, space is closer than the sea.
>
> Gravity in low Earth orbit is almost as strong as gravity on the surface. The Space Station hasn't escaped Earth's gravity at all; it's experiencing about 90% the pull that we feel on the surface.
>
> To avoid falling back into the atmosphere, you have to go sideways really, really fast.
>
> The speed you need to stay in orbit is about 8 kilometers per second.

In the following I am assuming that with going to orbit you mean reaching the height above sea corresponding to LEO (low Earth orbit), since obviously running until reaching a velocity of 8 km/s would require a level of doping not yet on the roadmap of any doping developer.

So, is it possible to build a stair raising up to 100 km above sea level?

No, it's not possible. It would crumble under its own weight. Calculation show that for Earth any structure can't go past about 10 km before being too heavy to sustain itself. And there are still 90 km to go.

Comment: With a tall enough staircase, you can achieve orbital velocity "for free" by sapping the earth's own rotational inertia, which is the principle behind space elevators - a staircase to GEO would put you in orbit, no running required. But that requires another couple of orders of magnitude of altitude, which is clearly not possible for a staircase.

Comment: GEO orbit would be 30 000 km away. If you could build a stairway, who would use it? 30 000 km upwards per stair :-)

Comment: 10km is the limit for natural materials, but a mountain made out of resin epoxy laminated carbon fiber should be able to reach ~ 40km, and there are some theoretical configurations of continuous carbon fibers that should be able to do 100km if made into a mountain.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: Just build the spiral staircase around the carbon nanotube cable suspended from geosync (space elevator).

Comment: That is probably true.

Comment: @Joshua ... The mankind has already tried that once. Shortly after, they went on a long journey away from each other. Now, if you were to retry that feat, I suggest you stick with the original name. BABEL = Brick Assembly Beyond Earth's Low orbit

Comment: Might be able to hit those heights if you use active support mechanisms like particle fountains or orbital loops. Or there’s always the joy of space elevators if you can pull some material science magic out of your plothole.

Answer (score 9):

A simple stairway is going to collapse as L.Dutch says.  However, if you're willing to get sufficiently complex you can build active supports capable of handling it.  (For the simplest systems, look at [Launch Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_loop) or [Space Fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_fountain).)  Several problems remain, though:

As others have mentioned, hypoxia.  Above 8km survival without oxygen is a temporary thing--the best can climb up to the 8,848m summit of Everest but you better get back down promptly.

There is also the problem that orbit is about speed, the only way you're walking to orbit is if it's synchronous.

Finally, even if we ignore the oxygen problem you will have **major** food problems.  Food isn't all that energetic, the tyranny of the rocket equation still applies even though we aren't using a rocket.  (Climbing to low orbit altitude is possible but requires more than 10% of your total weight to be food.  I don't know how much more you'll need in water.)

Edit:  My comparison to the rocket equation seems to have provoked some disagreement.  I was talking about the exponential fuel (food) use, not whether it could be done at all.  Think of rockets in deep space where you don't run into structural strength limits supporting it against gravity.

Lets consider Nuclear Hoagie's 4MJ example.  That's the energy to lift 40kg (apparently we are dealing with a darn small person!) 100km.  To accomplish that he started with 8MJ of fuel and climbed a total of 200km.  Quite workable.

But now lets climb to 300km (LEO, but you're not going fast enough.)  We need 8MJ of food at 200km which means we need 16MJ of food at 175km, 32MJ at 150km and so on for a total of 2048MJ when we started and a total climb of 51,200km.  Looks rather like the rocket equation to me.  Note that if you can maintain 1km/hr of climb (which I seriously doubt!!) you're still looking at nearly 6 years to do this.

Lets go up to 400km.  The odds are very high you're dead first.

Comment: Since we have a rigid structure, we're not truly restricted by the rocket equation, since you can take multiple trips and leave fuel behind which does not have to spend energy fighting gravity. Take more food than you need, climb partway up (perhaps 25%), leave a stash, and climb back down. Keep doing that until you have a sufficient stockpile of food 25% of the way up the stairs, at which point you repeat the process with trips between 25% ad 50%, and so on. If you're willing to take many trips, you only need to carry an arbitrarily small amount of food with you at any point.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie My gut feeling is that when you integrate over all the individual trips you end up at the rocket equation... that is, you still need to take a ton or whatever overall to the 10th floor in order to get a kg payload eventually to the 1000th. It's probably much worse than your typical rocket because we are not hollow even when exhausted ;-) (means, we have a terrible (dead weight)/(payload+fuel) ratio). Sure, if you just look at the *last* trip it looks really good, but you are kinda ignoring the bulk of the effort.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't think that's so, as you don't have to carry ever-increasing amounts of fuel. The rocket equation shows that if gravity were much higher, leaving earth would be impossible with known fuels. That's not the case here - under high gravity, you could just carry 1 grain of rice up 1 step, and repeat. Once you have enough rice on the second step, you repeat the problem recursively, but you never have to carry more than a single grain of rice at any time. The *total* energy used increases (which is the result of the integration), but that's not the rocket equation.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie But with enough gravity you cannot climb stairs either!?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, but that point only comes once gravity is so great that the rocket motor/legs can't even move an empty rocket/body. So long as you can carry your own body weight plus one grain of rice, you can climb arbitrarily high. Without a way to store fuel at altitude, you could only climb as high as one grain of rice would let you. Suppose a rocket can just barely lift off when carrying X amount of fuel - if your trip requires more energy than that, it is impossible. But if you can stock fuel at altitude, you can get there and never have to carry more than X.

Comment: As an example, say I want to climb to a height that requires a 4MJ change in potential, but I can't carry more than 2MJ worth of food. A rocket won't get there. But I can take 2MJ worth of food 25% of the way up, eat 1MJ, and leave 1MJ there. I come back down and repeat 3 times. The 4th time, I'm 25% of the way up with 4MJ stored. Now I climb to 50% and carry 2MJ, eating one and leaving one. Repeat, and now I'm at 50% with 2MJ stored. I can now climb the rest of the way, completing a trip that required a 4MJ change in potential despite never carrying more than 2MJ worth of fuel.

Comment: Perhaps hydroponics installed along the stairs. Travelers both harvest from and tend to the plants as they pass, and the composting toilets solve another important problem. It's a bit hard to get going, but once you're all the way up you can harvest comets to replace any leaks in the system. Probably the best type of plant to use would be something that grows fairly vertically, can be dried for long term storage, and has a good nutritional profile (good for the heart!)... Of course, things might also get a bit fragrant from the gastrointestinal results of that much legume consumption.

Answer (score 9):

#### First build your space elevator

A [space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) is a giant cable reaching down to the Earth's surface from a satellite in geostationary orbit (35,786 km).  With the cable touching down on the surface, essentially it is a giant tower, except a tower supported from the *top* instead of standing on the ground.  The concept of space elevators has been discussed in massive length for decades, and the consensus is there is no fundamental reason why it could not be made to work, given the right materials.

There is the slight problem that we do not currently have any materials with enough tensile strength for a cable that long to take its own weight.  Carbon nanotubes individually appear to have enough strength, but we would need nanotubes 35,786km long.  As of November last year, [the longest nanotubes ever created in bulk were 14cm](https://newatlas.com/materials/longest-carbon-nanotube-forests-record/).  So we're a long way off yet.

#### Then build your spiral staircase

Every concept for a space elevator allows for a vehicle to "climb" the cable. 35,786km is a long way!  But in principle there is absolutely no reason why you couldn't put a spiral staircase around the cable though.  At a standard stair riser height of 20cm, you'll need 178.93 million stairs.  There are [1665 stairs to the top of the Eiffel tower](https://www.toureiffel.paris/en/faq/spot/how-can-you-climb-eiffel-tower-foot#:%7E:text=How%20can%20you%20climb%20the,not%20open%20to%20the%20public.), for comparison.

If we already have space elevators, then we already also have climber vehicles.  So you could build something which would automatically work its way up the cable, installing stairs as it went.

#### Then put on your pressure suit

Above 3km altitude you start to need need oxygen, and above 15km you need a [pressure suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_suit).  A standard NASA space suit would be perfectly adequate, although the bulk and weight are not going to help your climbing ability.

#### And then start climbing

As you might expect for any human activity, [some people do it competitively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stair_climbing#Records).  Let's say you took Christian Riedl (13.14 km climbed in 12 hours) and started him at the bottom.  Clearly it's going to take more than a day to climb it, so it's fair to reckon on no more than 12 hours of climbing a day.  No-one's done this in a space suit, of course, but let's be ludicrously optimistic and say it wouldn't slow him down too much.

Then climbing all the way to geostationary orbit would take someone at his level of fitness a total of 2723 days, or a little under 7 1/2 years.  Assuming they can keep up 13.14km a day, with no rest days.  And of course disregarding the space suit.

#### Don't forget to pre-order pizza, beer and oxygen for delivery

With a minimum of 7 1/2 years climbing ahead of you, clearly you can't carry everything you'll need.  Fortunately you already have climbing vehicles - after all, one fitted the staircase for you.  So there could be a pod tracking your progress as you go up, giving you somewhere to sleep in each night, and nipping back to the bottom regularly to stock up on food, water, air, spare parts for your space suit, and anything else you need.

With access to supplies, after that it simply is a question of how long you want to keep going.  Clearly this is a long time, but it's certainly something you could achieve within your life if you wanted to.

#### In short...

Space elevators aren't a ridiculous idea - they're just a bit ahead of what we can do right now.  If you could build a space elevator, then you could build a staircase around it, and climb it.

But you probably don't want to.

Comment: What a great answer, one can learn so much from this :)

Comment: You don't actually need climbing vehicles to supply food for you. You can just climb up partway and leave a cache of food and supplies, and then climb back down to get more, like mountain climbers do. Unfortunately, this would mean that a single O(N) trip up the staircase may instead become an O(N^2) set of progressively longer trips, all of which except for the last one are solely to leave caches for later use.

Comment: @SomeGuy True, but as you say, it exponentially extends the task. Using a climbing vehicle for resupply  ensures this could be done within a human lifespan.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

The first step is walking out of the atmosphere.  To do this with anywhere near current technology, you'll need a dynamic structure.  This is a structure that isn't supported by compression or tension, but rather by shooting it with bullets.

You shoot it with bullets, catch those bullets with electromagnets, and fire them back down.  Which then fires them back up.  This requires constant power, but has more lift:weight than any practical material we have.

Getting this to work shouldn't take more than a few decades, and probably investment levels greater than the Apollo program.

But a stair case outside of the atmosphere is not orbit.  Orbit is, as many have noted, not far away -- it is fast away.  To be in orbit you need a large horizontal velocity.

Every child knows how to convert climbing a stair case (or a ladder) into horizontal velocity.  You simply have it gain more height, then add a slide.

The ISS moves under 8 km/s at 408 km above the ground.  Ignoring inverse square law, this simply requires a frictionless slide that goes down 3200 km to reach that speed.

But the inverse square law kicks in.  A rule of thumb is that the KE required to orbit half that required to escape the gravity well at that height; you have to reach 1/2 of the distance to 0 gravitational potential.  Gravitational potential is hyperbolic (shrinks with 1/r), so to orbit 6500 km away from the Earth's core, you need to slide down from 13000 km away from the Earth's core, or the top of your slide needs to be 7000 km away from Earth, then slide down the frictionless side to ISS orbital height, and at the bottom you'll be moving at orbital velocity.

(Gravitational potential energy is $\frac{K}{r}$ for some $K$.  We need $\frac{K}{r_1} = 2\frac{K}{r_0}$, or $r_1 = 2r_0$.)

Such a structure is going to be much harder than the simple "stairway outside of atmosphere".

Also, the power budget required to dynamically support a 7000 km tall staircase is going to be pretty crazy.

This should quantitatively make clear that orbit is **fast** more than **far** away; we spend 400 km reaching orbit, then 16 times that building up the kinetic energy to get up to orbital speed.  Now, the climbing is easier at the top of the slide compared to orbit (by a factor of 4 in fact), but that is a long long way to climb.

Answer (score 1):

How feasible? Ridiculously unfeasible. Possible? Yes.

As already said, standard construction materials could not do this beyond a certain height. But three components can work together to achieve the end result, in theory.

1. Compression: The lower stage of the staircase is supported from below. There will be some height at which the weight of the structure will crush itself, and that will be far below the elevation of low earth orbit. At this height, you must start adding the second technology into your construction:
2. Tension: The upper segment of the structure must be held from above by suspension cables, constructed like a space elevator. The whole structure lacks any lateral support and needs the third component:
3. Propulsion: Wind and shear forces will constantly try to topple your structure, and send your space anchors adrift. Components will need to have maneuvering engines at intervals to offset these forces, and correct for any unexpected impacts. These modules require energy, and specifically, components outside the atmosphere will require reaction mass (fuel) to stabilize them.

So you can stabilize the lower sections with electrically powered propellers, but when the air runs out you need to have fuel delivered to the upper components.

Feasible? No. But not impossible.

Can you walk up it? Only with a suit, oxygen, rest periods, and food.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a DIY store.
Buy 1 standard DIY staircase kit.
Put in into a space-craft.
Launch into orbit.
While there make (assemble) it.

All done.

You never mentioned in your question that the staircase had to be walked all the way into orbit. Just that is is a standard staircase that is **made** in orbit.

Comment: Well you are right but. Not really the point.

Comment: Also, go to the spacecraft store